# I can not make work the action of the button in a CustomCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I am using the `UICollectionView` and I created for my "cell" class `CustomCell`, where inside I instantiated a button. If I put the action in "`CustomCell.m`" responds the log and writes me something, but I need to use the action button in my class that contains the `UICollectionView`.

I used it for this reason the delegates, but nevertheless I do not work.

How can I fix?

**This is the code that I added to CustomCell.h:**

```
@class CustomCell;

@protocol CustomCellDelegate
- (void)btnSaveColor:(CustomCell *)sender;
@end

@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCustomCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bgCustomCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *RCustomCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *GCustomCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *BCustomCell;
- (IBAction)btnSaveColor:(id)sender;

@end
```

**This is the code that I added to CustomCell.m**

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (IBAction)btnSaveColor:(CustomCell *)sender {
    [_delegate btnSaveColor:self];
}

@end
```

**This is the code entered in ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface gradientViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, CustomCellDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *hexCode;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDest;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *gradientCollectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *gradientArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *gradientArrayToWhite;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *allGradient;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *reverse;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sorted;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bgHEXColorGradient;
- (IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bgBack;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *ColorSchemeAnalagous;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *ColorSchemeComplementary;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *ColorSchemeTriad;

@end
```

**and this one in ViewController.m**

```
#import "gradientViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIColor+Expanded.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ColorUtils.h"
#import "MPColorTools.h"
#import "RecipeCollectionHeaderView.h"
#import "UIColor+Colours.h"

@interface gradientViewController ()

@end

@implementation gradientViewController

- (void)btnSaveColor:(CustomCell *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Funziona il delegato!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this line of code:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

with this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;
```

I set also weak like property because with assign you have a strong object and in the `UICollectionView` then your Cell couldn't be released

Comment: when you make the cell ad the end before to return the cell you set the cell delegate like that cell.delegate = self;

Comment: @GianfrancoCotumaccio yes is the same but is good thing do like that :)